# Moving jQuery Slider as a div animates positions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to create a timeline player.

I have a div object which moves from one side of the screen to another (i.e. using animate() to change the 'left' position of the div). Lets assume this animation takes 5 seconds to happen.

I would like that a jQuery Slider keeps incrementing bit by bit alongside the animation. The slider must take 5 seconds as well to reach its end to matchup up with the animation it is tracking.

Anyone got any ideas how this can be implemented?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmm. The slider has a handle (an `a` element) with `style="left: X%;"`.
What about animating this handle in the same speed as the other animation? Here's an example:

```
var $slider = $('#slider').slider(); // initialize the slider
var $handle = $slider.find('a'); // get the UI handle
var $other  = $('#other');

function moveHandle(perc, duration) {
  $slider.slider('disable').css('opacity', 1); // we don't want the user to
                                               // move it while animating
  $handle.animate({
    left: perc + '%'
  }, duration, function() {
    $slider.slider('enable');
  });
}
moveHandle(100, 2000);

$other.animate({
  left: 300 // replace 300px with whatever you want
}, 2000);
```

A working demo: http://jsbin.com/iwise/36
You're free to extend or modify it however you want.

Answer (score 0):

I question why you want the slider to be governed by the animated object, rather than having the slider control the animation. If you let the playbar control the animation, the user can shuffle around as expected. I've put my working demo at http://jsbin.com/ijoka. The idea is there's an interval timer that increments the playhead when playing, and the *slide* and *slidechange* events trigger the animation.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var playing = false;
        var interval;
        var i = 0;

        $(function() {
                $('#slider').slider({min: 0, max: 100});
                $('#slider').bind('slide', function(e, ui) { i = ui.value; a(ui.value);}).bind('slidechange', function(e, ui) { a(ui.value);});

        });

        function a(p) {
         $('#box').css('left', p + "%");
        }

        function play() {
            if(playing) {
                playing = false;
                clearInterval(interval);
            } else {
                i = $('#slider').slider('value');
                playing = true;
                interval = setInterval(step, 100);
            }
        }

        function step() {
            i = i + 2;
            $('#slider').slider('value', i);
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: cbeer, you are right. My eventual goal is to have the slider 'control' the animation, and hence my simplified question above.

Now as shown in your example, and as I suspected when thinking of a similar solution, the animation is very jerky. I know this can be sorted by having a smaller incrementing value, but will this be ever as smooth as jQuery.animate()?

Comment: Incrementing by a smaller value would certainly help -- I've chosen 10 ticks/s, which is low + well into the range of perception, so the more ticks/s the less jerky it will appear. I imagine jQuery.animate() uses a similar system of ticks, but I haven't looked at those internals (there's also a possibility they can use some of the new css animations to smooth it out even more).